# Declaring struct as pointer so it can be checked whether it is initialized

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, struct, null

In the code below, I want to know whether or not the `viewTransform` struct is initialized, to determine whether or not to rotate my views. So I made `viewTransform` a pointer, instead of just a regular variable.

Is this good programming practice, or are there some potential caveats?

If I had to, I could instead declare a `BOOL` to keep track of whether or not `viewTransform` has been initialized.

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    CGAffineTransform *viewTransform = NULL;

    if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        *viewTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        *viewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 1.0f);
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        *viewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -0.5f);
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        *viewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5f);
    }

    if (viewTransform != NULL)
    {
        for (UIView *view in self.autoRotateViews)
        {
            [view setTransform:(*viewTransform)];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2CO3 is correct that what you've written will crash.

You could just tack `else return;` on to the end of your if-else-if-... chain to avoid the whole need to check if the transform was set.

Edited to clarify: Of course, I mean the above as an alternative to using a pointer. So, I'm suggesting just reverting `viewTransform` to being a `CGAffineTransform`, not a pointer, and then returning early if you didn't set it to anything.

Answer (score 1):

This will crash like hell. You're declaring viewTransform to be NULL, then dereferencing it. Instead, don't make it a pointer. Use

```
CGAffineTransform viewTransform;
```

instead, and yes, track the initialization state with a BOOL.

If you really want to avoid using a BOOL at the cost of overcomplicating things, you can also do:

```
CGAffineTransform *viewTransform = NULL;
if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
{
    viewTransform = malloc(sizeof(*viewTransform));
    NSAssert(viewTransform != NULL, @"malloc() failed");
    *viewTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

and then check for viewTransform to be NULL (uninitialized) or non-NULL (initialized).

If you choose this (superfluously complicated) approach, don't forget to `free()` the transform pointer after use.

Answer (score 0):

```
    switch (orientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        break;
    default:
        return;
}
```